# Created cookie in code, deleted cookie from browser, page can still read the deleted cookie. How?

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

I have the following C# code which logs the user's url in a cookie. If the cookie already exists, it appends the new value to the existing value separated by a pipe character. My ASPX page looks up this cookie, chops up the values based on the pipe character and binds them to a grid. So far so good. But when I go to Internet Options in my browser and clear my cookies, temp files etc and refresh the page, the page can still read the values from the cookie. It appears that the cookie did not deleted after all. It is being persisted no matter how. What gives? If the user clears the cookies from their browser, the grid control in my ASPX should be empty. The page is not using caching or anything.

```
HttpCookie recentlyViewedCookie = Request.Cookies["RecentlyViewedCookie"];
        if (recentlyViewedCookie != null)
        {
            string value = recentlyViewedCookie.Value;
            value = string.Format("{0}|{1}*{2}", value, DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"), Request.Url.ToString());
            recentlyViewedCookie.Value = value;
            Response.Cookies.Add(recentlyViewedCookie);
        }
        else
        {
            recentlyViewedCookie = new HttpCookie("RecentlyViewedCookie");
            recentlyViewedCookie.Value = string.Format("{0}*{1}", DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"), Request.Url.ToString());
            recentlyViewedCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1);
            Response.Cookies.Add(recentlyViewedCookie);
        }
```

Thanks for any answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all **is NOT a good practice to ask from your user to clear all the cookies**, for your page to run correct.

Second, you did not say what browser you use, because this is a browser part, and when you clear the cookies you need to close also the browser, or at least do not have open your page (because you say "refresh the page"). If you have clear the cookies, **but you have open the page on the browser, the browser have been keep the cookie for that page** - is part of the render that have done, is part of the javascript global values for that page, so the cookie exist until you close AND the page of you. The clear all cookies is not clear the active memory, just delete all the cookies files from the cache.

at the end I suggest to think a different method for your page flow actions, and NOT ask from your user to clear all the cookies.

Comment: May be I worded the question a little differently, but I never asked the user to clear the cookie on their machine. I was just testing my cookie functionality by letting my code create the cookie, then I (for testing) deleted cookie in my browser (IE) while on the same page, refreshed the page and could still see the values in my cookie. Taking your advice, I deleted the cookies in my browser, then closed my browser, re-opened the page and my grid is now empty which is what I expected it to be. Closing the browser and re-opening it did the trick. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is this block of code:

```
    if (recentlyViewedCookie != null)
    {
        string value = recentlyViewedCookie.Value;
        value = string.Format("{0}|{1}*{2}", value, DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"), Request.Url.ToString());
        recentlyViewedCookie.Value = value;
        Response.Cookies.Add(recentlyViewedCookie);
    }
```

You did not set the cookie's expiration date.  If a cookie does not have an expiration date, it is a "session cookie" and is held in memory until the browser is closed-- it is never written to disk-- so deleting all the cookies from disk won't affect it.

You might think that the expiration date from the initial cookie creation would persist, but this is not the case.  The server doesn't have access to the original cookie and has no idea what the expiration is set to.  So it just writes a set-cookie header without any expiration date at all, turning the cookie into a session cookie.